Make user create a unique username when logging in with Google Sign-In Firebase
I have two sign-in methods in my Firebase application

Email
Google Sign-in

With email i have set it up so that a user must create a unique username when signing up.
I am now attempting to do the same with Google sign-in. But how can this be achieved?
Option 1 (additionalUserInfo.isNewUser)
I can check isNewUser but at this point firestore has already created the account. So it does not serve any purpose...
 let gidSignInResult = try await GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: topVC)
    guard let idToken: String = gidSignInResult.user.idToken?.tokenString else {
        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }
    let accessToken: String = gidSignInResult.user.accessToken.tokenString
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)
    let (model, newUser) = try await signInHandle(credential: credential)
    
    if (newUser) {
       //Go to Sign up where user chooses a username and then logs in again 
    } else {
       //Login  
    }

Option 2
I could also make the user put in a username and afterwards sign in with Google Auth. But this would make the user return to the sign up page every time they log out and in...
Option 3
The best option seems to be to let the user log in with Google Auth first and then send the user to a form page where they fill in a unique username if they don't have one. But is there a better alternative?

Approach 3 is indeed fairly common. In this flow you'd have the user complete the sign-in to Google first, and then check if you already have a registration document in Firestore for the user. If not, send them to the registration page - and have them register a unique username.
The common approaches to do this have been covered before, so I recommend checking:

How to enforce Uniqueness in a Property of a document field in Google Cloud Firestore
How to set cloud firestore rules to check username uniqueness in Swift app
Firestore unique index or unique constraint?
Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names

